# Error compiling Node App - Variable 'Promise' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'PromiseConstructor'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm running "tsc" and getting the following errors

```
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(554,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Promise' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'PromiseConstructor'. 
typings/globals/require/index.d.ts(367,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'Require'.
```

typings.json

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "requirejs": "registry:npm/requirejs#2.2.0+20160319062357"
  }
}
```

packages.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "promise": "^7.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.16",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by literally editing it and modifying the lines it was complaining about, but I am sure this is a workaround and not the correct fix

typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts line 554 made it type any
typings/globals/require/index.d.ts line 367 made it type NodeRequire